# Java: Creating a toString method for Polynomial class

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java: Creating a toString method for Polynomial class.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525210/java-creating-a-tostring-method-for-polynomial-class)

```
public String toString(){
        String mytoString="";
        if(!a.equals(0)){
            mytoString = a.toString() + "x^2";
        }
        if(!b.equals(0)){
            mytoString += b.toString() + "x";
        }
        if(!c.equals(0)){
            mytoString += c.toString(); 
        }
        return mytoString;
    }
```

This is the code I have.
The release tests for the project says I'm failing toStringPositive.
I'm having trouble figuring out what exactly is wrong with my code.
Any help is appreciated.

I have to create a string representing the Polynomial ax^2+bx+c.
These are the **specifications**:

- There are never any spaces in the
  string.
- Do not include an "*" in the "x^2"
  and "x" terms.  (i.e., create
  "23x^2", not "23*x^2").   If there
  are negative terms, they should be
  represented by subtraction, not
  addition of a negative term (i.e.,
  create "2x^2+4x-6", not "2x^2+4x+-6".
- If there are any terms with a 0
  coefficient, then skip that term
  (i.e., create "2x^2-6", not
  "2x^2+0x-6").
- If all 3 coefficients are 0, then the
  string should be "0" If there are any
  terms with a 1 coefficient, then
  display that coefficient (i.e.,
  create "2x^2+1x+3", not "2x^2+x+3").
- If the decimal component of a
  coefficient is 0, then do not include
  a decimal portion for that
  coefficient (i.e., create "23x", not
  "23.0x").  Note that the
  MyDouble.toString() method does this
  for you automatically.